# Error when executing Python 3.5.1 code using Windows 8.1

Tags: python, windows, import

I have a question regarding an error when I try to run a Python program. I am using Python 3.5.1 under Windows 8.1. The code and the error message are attached below. The code works just fine on Mac with Python 3.5.1.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.INFO)

def logger(func):
    def log_func(*args):
        logging.info('Running "{}" with arguments {}'.format(func.__name__, arg))
        print(func(*args))
    return log_func

def add(x, y):
    return x+y

def sub(x,y):
    return x-y

add_logger = logger(add)
sub_logger = logger(sub)
```

Tracback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\firstclass.py", line 1, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\linecache.py", line 8, in <module>
    import functools
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\functools.py", line 22, in <module>
    from types import MappingProxyType
ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType'
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Sorry! I have done so. This is my first post on stackoverflow!

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: When running this code on python 3.5.1 using windows 8.1, I receive the error enclosed in the comment by the end of the code. How can I get the code to run on windows?

Comment: Probably you have a file named "types.py" that's shadowing the standard library module of the same name.

Comment: Since I am new to python, could you please suggest how can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe rename it to something else? Don't need to know Python for that...

Comment: Check `import types; print(types.__file__)`. If it's not "C:\Python35-32\lib\types.py", just rename it.

Comment: Thanks guys. The code worked after renaming my created file "types.py".